# What is the main idea of Ibsen's Ghosts, and what does the ending of the play mean?

Tags: scandinavian-languages, henrik-ibsen, ghosts

What is the main idea of Ibsen's *Ghosts*, and what does the ending of the play mean? Some comments said that Osvald inherited the disease from his father. But *Ghosts* was a play that is a sacarsm of the society. It seems the plot of the disease is a bit off topic. Why did the writer arranged the plot of an inherited disease?

Comment: One question: did you realize that the disease is syphilis, a venereal disease, and not a typical inherited genetic disorder.

Comment: It's been a long, long time since I read the play, so I can't answer the question adequately without rereading it. Looking online, the word "syphilis" is never used in it, and it's referred to by a very obscure euphemism. I don't know whether this euphemism was equally obscure in the original Norwegian. Even if it was, the prevalence and severity of syphilis at the time would have made the meaning much clearer than it is today.